# How to make a sword appear from behind a tree in 2D Animation

Tags: animation, 2d

[image]

Hello, i am brand new to blender.
I am trying to make a short Stickman animation for learning purposes.
I would like to make the sword appear from behind the tree, and not in front of the tree as it does now.
I have been looking for tutorials, but i can't find any answers on how to do this.
I thought maybe i could make the tree a layer somehow and get the sword to be behind that layer, but dunno how. 
The best clue i got was somebody talking about "shrinkwrap" tho, i don't think it's meant for stuff like this ?
Any tips would be a great help! :)

Best regards Mathias
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey there, may i suggest to add the "Outliner" and "Object Data Properties" tab to your screenshot, as it may be making a difference depending on if the sword is it's own object grease pencil or not and maybe you could elaborate a bit what you tried, to make it easier to help understand your current situation and eventually solve your problem.

Comment: i have downloaded a image of the sword from google, and masked it in gimp, then added it to blender.
I drew the tree with the draw tool, and haven't done anything else. 

i'm not sure how to find the object data properties.
and not sure if my second screenshot has the outliner you were talking about ?
I know it seems a bit effortless, but i have only been using the program for about 10 hours, and have been stuck here for the past 3 hours.

haven't tried so much,other than finding answers on google, since i have no idea where to begin atm.

Comment: Realized that i could just fill out the tree with the draw tool, and that would make the sword get behind the tree. but i would like it if the tree didn't have to be filled out with the draw tool, like i did at the last screenshot

Comment: Okay, i have here a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/8Jh5ByC) with the areas marked to make it easier to understand my previous comment. You should add information to your question using the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/172857/edit) link, since it's your question, you always have the right to edit/correct/add more to make it easier to help. In that regard you can also allow others to help by sharing your file using [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), where you need to copy this questions address for it to work, since it's only for questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to go to object mode, then duplicate the tree with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, then extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>), and fill (<kbd>F</kbd>):

[image]

between the vertices at the edges, to make an object that will cover the sword (or anything else), then make the material of this object just filled white (or whatever colour* your background is):

*I'm British so I spell it properly

[image]

then that should cover the sword perfectly behind the tree. If the sword is still in front the tree, then check that it is behind the tree in 3D space.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton, That did the trick! :)

Comment: Glad to help! (and I have to add more characters to post this)